# Launch Eclipse Program Exported From File

Tags: java, console, manifest, launch

I already read many questions it the same subject, but none solved my problem..

I know that I can easly launch my app using this command on console java -jar myappname.jar

But what I want is to click on my .jar file exported by eclipse and it launches console with my app inside, do u understand?

I done the export using this configs :

File>Export>Jar File
Selected all the classes of my project
Selected "Export generated class files and resources"
Selected "Export java source files and resources"
Selected "Compress the contents of the Jar File"

Pressed Next

Selected "Export class files with compile errors"
Selected "Export class files with compile warnings"

Pressed Next

Selected "Generate the manifest file"
Selected Seal the Jar

And on "Select the class of the Application entry point:"
I choose my class where is the void main method .

the jar appears on my desktop, but then, when I double click it doesnt launch the console. why??
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Launching a jar by double-clicking the file (or shortcut) will not display a terminal. One workaround is to change the default execute action in your operating system for .jar files to open a terminal and execute the command from within the terminal. A script like the following might do the trick (using Bash):

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x java -jar $*
sleep 3
```

Then right-click on the jar file and choose the script as the default program to run for that file type.

Disclaimer: the above script actually fails for me. It works fine if the command being run in the terminal is "top", so it looks like you may need to tweak this a bit.

Comment: really? I cant launch them on console by native java? :s

Comment: You can try using the jar generate by eclipse from console. If that works fine then jar is correct you need to follow what Nate suggested, if not there might be some problem in the generated jar.

Comment: @TiagoM I'm not sure what you mean by "launch them on console" since you stated in your question that you know you can launch it from the console. When you double click on the jar file, the operating system is doing a `java -jar <your jar>` but does not show the console. See my revised answer for a possible workaround with a script.

Comment: Yes the operating system is doing a java -jar <my jar> when I double click it, i know that. what I would want is to show the console when I double click my app ... I think u got it, and already told me that is kinda hard... I want to distribute to friends, they would need all to do that tweaks .. ? thanks

Comment: It is common to include a script to launch your jar file when distributing your program. The script would look very similar to what I already have above, and you can then give it a meaningful icon.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS.
If you use Windows, you can create .bat or .exe files. You can find 'how-to-create' tutorials on the internet. 
If you use Unix based OS, you can just set the jar to be the executable.
A third party OS probaly has it's own way to set to executable.
This is the only way I am aware of.